# calender not working after extension changes from html to jsp

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, calendar

html and i have few codes in javascript to display timepick(like a calender). It works perfect when it is in html but i need it in jsp. I am poor in javascript so please tell me how to make it work perfectly in jsp also

here is the code

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<STYLE>
    input {      
      font-size:11px;
    }
  </STYLE>


 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

   <script language="javaScript" type="text/javascript" src="calendar.js"></script>

<link href="calendar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
html, body, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, img, dl,
  dt, dd, ol, ul, li, table, tr, td, form, object, embed,
  article, aside, command, details, fieldset,
  figcaption, figure, footer, group, header, hgroup, legend
 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  }
html {
  font: 82.5% verdana, helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
  line-height: 1;
  direction: ltr;
  }
  html, body {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  } 

  table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  }


  .signin-header
  {
  padding: 10px 12px 5px;
  background:#00AAFF;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  width: 362px;
  float: right;
  }
  .signin-box
 {
  padding: 20px 25px 15px;
  background:#DEDEDE;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  width: 335px;
  float: right;
  }

  .button {
  min-width: 46px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #444;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 27px;
  padding: 0 8px;
  line-height: 27px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transition: all 0.218s;
  border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  cursor: default;
  }

  *+html .button {
  min-width: 70px;
  }
  button.button,
  input[type=submit].button {
  height: f1f1f1px;
  line-height: 29px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  margin: 0;
  }

  .button:hover {
  border: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.0s;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  }
  .button:active {
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  }
  .button:visited {
  color: #666;
  }  
   .button-submit {
  border: 1px solid #3079ed;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  background-color: #4d90fe;
  }
  .button-submit:hover {
  border: 1px solid #2f5bb7;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  background-color: #357ae8;
  }
  button-submit:active {
  background-color: #357ae8;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  }

  .footer-bar {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 35px;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  overflow: hidden;
  }
          .footer {
  padding-top: 9px;
  font-size: .85em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: 0;
  }
  .footer ul {
  color: #999;
  float: left;
  max-width: 80%;
  }
  .footer ul li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 1.5em 0 0;
  }
  .footer a {
  color: #333;
  }
  .footer .lang-chooser-wrap {
  float: right;
  max-width: 20%;
  }
  .footer .lang-chooser-wrap img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .footer .attribution {
  float: right;
  }
  .footer .attribution span {
  vertical-align: text-top;
  }
  .content {
  padding: 0 44px;
  }

  .table{
    padding: 0 55px
  }
</style>


<script type="text/javascript">
function ccheck()
{
FirstName=document.f1.FirstName.value;
LastName=document.f1.LastName.value;
DOB=document.f1.DOB.value;
Email=document.f1.Email.value;
Phone=document.f1.Phone.value;
RegistrationNo=document.f1.RegistrationNo.value;
City=document.f1.City.value;
State=document.f1.State.value;
Country=document.f1.Country.value;
if(City=="" || City==null)
{
alert("Plz. Enter Your City");
document.f1.City.focus();
return false;
}
if(State=="" || State==null)
{
alert("Plz. Enter Your State");
document.f1.State.focus();
return false;
}
if(Country=="" || Country==null)
{
alert("Plz. Enter Your Country");
document.f1.Country.focus();
return false;
}
if(DOB=="" || DOB==null)
{
alert("Plz. Enter Your Date of Birth");
document.f1.DOB.focus();
return false;
}
if(Email=="" || Email==null )
{
alert("Plz. Enter Your Email");
document.f1.Email.focus();
return false;

}
if(Phone=="" || Phone==null)
{
alert("Plz. Enter Your Phone");
document.f1.Phone.focus();
return false;
}
if(RegistrationNo=="" || RegistrationNo==null)
{
alert("Plz. Enter Your Registration No");
document.f1.RegistrationNo.focus();
return false;
}
if(FirstName=="" || FirstName==null)
{
alert("Plz. Enter Your First Name");
document.f1.FirstName.focus();
return false;
}
if(LastName=="" || LastName==null)
{
alert("Plz. Enter Last Name");
document.f1.LastName.focus();
return false;
}
return true;
}
</script>


<title>My Appointments</title>
</head>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">



  var imagePath='timePickerImages/';

  var ie=document.all;
  var dom=document.getElementById;
  var ns4=document.layers;
  var bShow=false;
  var textCtl;

  function setTimePicker(t) {
    textCtl.value=t;
    closeTimePicker();
  }

  function refreshTimePicker(mode) {

    if (mode==0)
      { 
        suffix="am"; 
      }
    else
      { 
        suffix="pm"; 
      }

    sHTML = "<table><tr><td><table cellpadding=3 cellspacing=0 bgcolor='#f0f0f0'>";
    for (i=0;i<=11;i++) {

      sHTML+="<tr align=right style='font-family:verdana;font-size:9px;color:#000000;'>";

      if (i==0) {
        hr = 12;
      }
      else {
        hr=i;
      }  

      for (j=0;j<4;j++) {
        sHTML+="<td width=57 style='cursor:hand' onmouseover='this.style.backgroundColor=\"#66CCFF\"' onmouseout='this.style.backgroundColor=\"\"' onclick='setTimePicker(\""+ hr + ":" + padZero(j*15) + " " + suffix + "\")'><a style='text-decoration:none;color:#000000' href='javascript:setTimePicker(\""+ hr + ":" + padZero(j*15) + " " + suffix + "\")'>" + hr + ":"+padZero(j*15) + "<font color=\"#808080\">" + suffix + "</font></a></td>";
      }

      sHTML+="</tr>";
    }
    sHTML += "</table></td></tr></table>";
    document.getElementById("timePickerContent").innerHTML = sHTML;
  }

  if (dom){
    document.write ("<div id='timepicker' style='z-index:+999;position:absolute;visibility:hidden;'><table style='border-width:3px;border-style:solid;border-color:#0033AA' bgcolor='#ffffff' cellpadding=0><tr bgcolor='#0033AA'><td><table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width='100%' background='" + imagePath + "titleback.gif'><tr valign=bottom height=21><td style='font-family:verdana;font-size:11px;color:#ffffff;padding:3px' valign=center><B>&nbsp;&nbsp;Select a Time&nbsp;&nbsp;</B></td><td><img id='iconAM' src='" + imagePath + "am1.gif' onclick='document.getElementById(\"iconAM\").src=\"" + imagePath + "am1.gif\";document.getElementById(\"iconPM\").src=\"" + imagePath + "pm2.gif\";refreshTimePicker(0)' style='cursor:hand'></td><td><img id='iconPM' src='" + imagePath + "pm2.gif' onclick='document.getElementById(\"iconAM\").src=\"" + imagePath + "am2.gif\";document.getElementById(\"iconPM\").src=\"" + imagePath + "pm1.gif\";refreshTimePicker(1)' style='cursor:hand'></td><td align=right valign=center>&nbsp;<img onclick='closeTimePicker()' src='" + imagePath + "close.gif'  STYLE='cursor:hand'>&nbsp;</td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td colspan=2><span id='timePickerContent'></span></td></tr></table></div>");
    refreshTimePicker(0);
  }

  var crossobj=(dom)?document.getElementById("timepicker").style : ie? document.all.timepicker : document.timepicker;
  var currentCtl

  function selectTime(ctl,ctl2) {
    var leftpos=0
    var toppos=0

    textCtl=ctl2;
    currentCtl = ctl
    currentCtl.src=imagePath + "timepicker2.gif";

    aTag = ctl
    do {
      aTag = aTag.offsetParent;
      leftpos  += aTag.offsetLeft;
      toppos += aTag.offsetTop;
    } while(aTag.tagName!="BODY");
    crossobj.left =  ctl.offsetLeft  + leftpos 
    crossobj.top = ctl.offsetTop +  toppos + ctl.offsetHeight +  2 
    crossobj.visibility=(dom||ie)? "visible" : "show"
    hideElement( 'SELECT', document.getElementById("calendar") );
    hideElement( 'APPLET', document.getElementById("calendar") );      
    bShow = true;
  }

  // hides <select> and <applet> objects (for IE only)
  function hideElement( elmID, overDiv ){
    if( ie ){
      for( i = 0; i < document.all.tags( elmID ).length; i++ ){
        obj = document.all.tags( elmID )[i];
        if( !obj || !obj.offsetParent ){
            continue;
        }
          // Find the element's offsetTop and offsetLeft relative to the BODY tag.
          objLeft   = obj.offsetLeft;
          objTop    = obj.offsetTop;
          objParent = obj.offsetParent;
          while( objParent.tagName.toUpperCase() != "BODY" )
          {
          objLeft  += objParent.offsetLeft;
          objTop   += objParent.offsetTop;
          objParent = objParent.offsetParent;
          }
          objHeight = obj.offsetHeight;
          objWidth = obj.offsetWidth;
          if(( overDiv.offsetLeft + overDiv.offsetWidth ) <= objLeft );
          else if(( overDiv.offsetTop + overDiv.offsetHeight ) <= objTop );
          else if( overDiv.offsetTop >= ( objTop + objHeight + obj.height ));
          else if( overDiv.offsetLeft >= ( objLeft + objWidth ));
          else
          {
          obj.style.visibility = "hidden";
          }
      }
    }
  }

  //unhides <select> and <applet> objects (for IE only)
  function showElement( elmID ){
    if( ie ){
      for( i = 0; i < document.all.tags( elmID ).length; i++ ){
        obj = document.all.tags( elmID )[i];
        if( !obj || !obj.offsetParent ){
            continue;
        }
        obj.style.visibility = "";
      }
    }
  }

  function closeTimePicker() {
    crossobj.visibility="hidden"
    showElement( 'SELECT' );
    showElement( 'APPLET' );
    currentCtl.src=imagePath + "timepicker.gif"
  }

  document.onkeypress = function hideTimePicker1 () { 
    if (event.keyCode==27){
      if (!bShow){
        closeTimePicker();
      }
    }
  }

  function isDigit(c) {

    return ((c=='0')||(c=='1')||(c=='2')||(c=='3')||(c=='4')||(c=='5')||(c=='6')||(c=='7')||(c=='8')||(c=='9'))
  }

  function isNumeric(n) {

    num = parseInt(n,10);

    return !isNaN(num);
  }

  function padZero(n) {
    v="";
    if (n<10){ 
      return ('0'+n);
    }
    else
    {
      return n;
    }
  }

  function validateDatePicker(ctl) {

    t=ctl.value.toLowerCase();
    t=t.replace(" ","");
    t=t.replace(".",":");
    t=t.replace("-","");

    if ((isNumeric(t))&&(t.length==4))
    {
      t=t.charAt(0)+t.charAt(1)+":"+t.charAt(2)+t.charAt(3);
    }

    var t=new String(t);
    tl=t.length;

    if (tl==1 ) {
      if (isDigit(t)) {
        ctl.value=t+":00 am";
      }
      else {
        return false;
      }
    }
    else if (tl==2) {
      if (isNumeric(t)) {
        if (parseInt(t,10)<13){
          if (t.charAt(1)!=":") {
            ctl.value= t + ':00 am';
          } 
          else {
            ctl.value= t + '00 am';
          }
        }
        else if (parseInt(t,10)==24) {
          ctl.value= "0:00 am";
        }
        else if (parseInt(t,10)<24) {
          if (t.charAt(1)!=":") {
            ctl.value= (t-12) + ':00 pm';
          } 
          else {
            ctl.value= (t-12) + '00 pm';
          }
        }
        else if (parseInt(t,10)<=60) {
          ctl.value= '0:'+padZero(t)+' am';
        }
        else {
          ctl.value= '1:'+padZero(t%60)+' am';
        }
      }
      else
           {
        if ((t.charAt(0)==":")&&(isDigit(t.charAt(1)))) {
          ctl.value = "0:" + padZero(parseInt(t.charAt(1),10)) + " am";
        }
        else {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
    else if (tl>=3) {

      var arr = t.split(":");
      if (t.indexOf(":") > 0)
      {
        hr=parseInt(arr[0],10);
        mn=parseInt(arr[1],10);

        if (t.indexOf("pm")>0) {
          mode="pm";
        }
        else {
          mode="am";
        }

        if (isNaN(hr)) {
          hr=0;
        } else {
          if (hr>24) {
            return false;
          }
          else if (hr==24) {
            mode="am";
            hr=0;
          }
          else if (hr>12) {
            mode="pm";
            hr-=12;
          }
        }

        if (isNaN(mn)) {
          mn=0;
        }
        else {
          if (mn>60) {
            mn=mn%60;
            hr+=1;
          }
        }
      } else {

        hr=parseInt(arr[0],10);

        if (isNaN(hr)) {
          hr=0;
        } else {
          if (hr>24) {
            return false;
          }
          else if (hr==24) {
            mode="am";
            hr=0;
          }
          else if (hr>12) {
            mode="pm";
            hr-=12;
          }
        }

        mn = 0;
      }

      if (hr==24) {
        hr=0;
        mode="am";
      }
      ctl.value=hr+":"+padZero(mn)+" "+mode;
    }
  }

</SCRIPT>





<body onload="document.f1.uid.focus()"  style="background-image:url('medical.jpg');background-position: center ">

<form id="f1" name="f1" action="registerServlet" method="post" onsubmit="return ccheck()" >

            <img  src="header.png"><br><br><br><br><br>
    <table >
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <td>

                        </td>
                        <td>image</td>
                        <td>
                            <table class="table" >
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="content">
                                        <div class="signin-header">
                                        <h3>My Appointments</h3>
                                        </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="content">
                                            <div align="center" class="signin-box">
                                                <table class="table">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td><b>Patient</b></td>
                                                        <td><select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select></td>
                                                    </tr>

                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td><b>DOB</b></td>
                                                        <td><input type="text" name="DOB"><a href="#" onClick="setYears(1947, 2013);
       showCalender(this, 'DOB');">
      <img src="calender.png"></a></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td><b>Start TIme</b></td>
                                                        <td><input id='timepicker1' name="StartTime" type='text' value='12:00 pm' size=8 maxlength=8 ONBLUR="validateDatePicker(this)"><IMG SRC="calender.png"  ALT=" Time!" ONCLICK="selectTime(this,timepicker1)" STYLE="cursor:hand"></td></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr >
                                                        <td><b>End Time</b></td>
                                                        <td><input id='timepicker1' type='text' name="EndTime" value='12:00 pm' size=8 maxlength=8 ONBLUR="validateDatePicker(this)"><IMG SRC="calender.png"  ALT=" Time!" ONCLICK="selectTime(this,timepicker1)" STYLE="cursor:hand"></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr >
                                                        <td><b>Description</b></td>
                                                        <td><input name="Description" type="text" /></td>
                                                    </tr>

                                                    <tr >
                                                        <td><input type="submit"
                                                                class="button button-submit" value="Submit" /></td>
                                                        <td><input type="reset" class="button button-submit"
                                                                value="Reset" /></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        </tr>
</table>

<div class="footer-bar">
    <img src="./header.png" align="left" >
</div>
</form>
<table id="calenderTable">
        <tbody id="calenderTableHead">
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4" align="center">
              <select onChange="showCalenderBody(createCalender(document.getElementById('selectYear').value,
               this.selectedIndex, false));" id="selectMonth">
                  <option value="0">Jan</option>
                  <option value="1">Feb</option>
                  <option value="2">Mar</option>
                  <option value="3">Apr</option>
                  <option value="4">May</option>
                  <option value="5">Jun</option>
                  <option value="6">Jul</option>
                  <option value="7">Aug</option>
                  <option value="8">Sep</option>
                  <option value="9">Oct</option>
                  <option value="10">Nov</option>
                  <option value="11">Dec</option>
              </select>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                <select onChange="showCalenderBody(createCalender(this.value, 
                document.getElementById('selectMonth').selectedIndex, false));" id="selectYear">
                </select>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <a href="#" onClick="closeCalender();"><font color="#003333" size="+1">X</font></a>
            </td>
          </tr>
       </tbody>
       <tbody id="calenderTableDays">
         <tr style="">
           <td>Sun</td><td>Mon</td><td>Tue</td><td>Wed</td><td>Thu</td><td>Fri</td><td>Sat</td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
       <tbody id="calender"></tbody>
    </table>

<!-- End Calender Script  --> 


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works exactly same way in JSP, there is no difference.

Comment: there three fields one for calender and 2 for time. start time and end time.did you check the time?

Comment: First of all, you should do your homework and learn some basics of HTML, CSS and JavaScript. You have dozens of errors all over the code.
For example:
- duplicate id "timepicker1"
- leaking variables suffix, sHTML, crossobj, obj etc. (you shall declare local variables using "var" at the start of each function)
- "ONCLICK" shall be lowercase
- scripts may be in the head or in the body tag, but not outside
...
If you fixed these "formal" errors, the problem would probably disappear. If not, you would have a solid basis to solve it.

Comment: OK, I posted somewhat cleaned code to http://jsfiddle.net/richard03/D67CC/ - please place it to your JSP and try if timepicker is working. If not, look if there is a javascript error in the javascript console of your browser (use Firefox or Chrome for that).

Comment: please tell me which part should i have to replace with your code

Comment: Does it work inside your JSP? My code is not exact subset of yours, so you shall clean up your code the way I did it. You cannot just "replace" some part of the code, it doesn't work that way. Try to compare my code and you original code, winMerge is good for that.

Comment: @Richards your code is working but it is not as per my need. what is wimMerge.i just want to make the time calender functional. so if possible please tell me how to do that. i do not have enough knowledge in javascript,so i am asking for your help

Comment: Sorry, I just realized I don't understand what do you need - I thought you need the timepicker working in JSP.

WinMerge is a software for comparing and merginig two text documents. Please use Google before you ask, it helps a lot.

Comment: @Richards yes timepicker as well as calender that means date picker and other fields. When i run your code it just gave me the timePicker. you can see the code in the question,all fields works perfectly except the timepicker.

Comment: TimePicker shall not affect the callendar. You shall separate your code to smallest independent parts possible and ensure they don't affect each other.